# Disable input fields based on UserRole Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages

I have a form with more than 50 no:of fields.
All those fields are not accessible to all userroles. Based on userroles i have disabled the fields like this.

```
<select id="DrpDwnFinalApprovalStatus" asp-for="ShipmentProfile.ApproverStatus" asp-items="@Model.Status" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@(Model.UserRole != "UserRoleA"?true:false)">
                     <option value="">Please Select</option>
                 </select>
```

But now the requirement has changed like , certain userroles can edit some sections
As in the above case i have to check for two userroles like if it is not UserRoleA and UserRoleB then the field is disabled.
Apart from this i need to check some status also. Which is the best approach server side or client side.
If its server side is there any sample code to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

You must always perform checks on the server. Client-side stuff is easily circumvented. It is easy for someone to use the browser dev tools to remove the disabled attribute on a form field, or craft an HTTP Post that includes anything they want.

Not sure what sample code you are expecting - it should be a simple if statement to check the role of the current user before you make any changes to properties.